# Is va_list incompatible between C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, variadic-functions

I'm using a library (GNU MicroHttpDaemon) which passes out error messages through a callback which takes a va_list. I pass in a function pointer and if an error occurs then my function is called with a va_list and some other parameters. My problem is that when I receive the va_list it is garbage and attempting to use it causes an exception to be thrown.
I am using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10. MicroHttpDaemon was built with the same compiler. My best guess for the cause is that MicroHttpDaemon is written in C, but I am using C++. Can anyone confirm that this is the issue? If it is then is there anything I can do to get the arguments into my C++ code?
My callback is below in case it's any use. Note that it is a static method, so should in general be fine to use as a C callback I think.

```
void HttpDaemon::parseMessageVa(void * arg, const char * fmt, va_list &ap)
{
    HttpDaemon *daemon = static_cast<HttpDaemon*> (arg);
    size_t n = vsnprintf(nullptr, 0, fmt, ap);
    char *buffer = nullptr;
    try
    {
        buffer = new char[n + 1];
        vsprintf(buffer, fmt, ap);
        try
        {
            daemon->m_lastMessage = std::string(buffer);
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            delete[] buffer;
            throw;
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        //buffer allocation failed
        daemon->m_lastMessage = "Memory allocation failure.";
    }
    if(buffer)
        delete[] buffer;
}
```

Comment: No, not that I'm aware of. Could you provide a [MCVE reproducing your problem please?]

Comment: Why are you manually managing memory and then trying to free it on all exit paths?  Just use one of `std::vector<char>` or `std::string`.  Particularly since you're going to convert it to `std::string` anyway.

Comment: Also, `va_list` is designed to be passed by value, perhaps something goes wrong when you make a reference to it.  Can you show the code that calls this?  (Or since it is a callback, makes the function pointer)

Comment: Including needed `#include` files? (None shown here).

Comment: `va_list &ap` -- a callback from C won't pass anything by reference. The function should take the list by value.

Comment: If you are explicitly casting function pointers, stop immediately.  When the signature is right, no cast will be needed.

Comment: @Phil Your code looks fairly bad. Why are you trying to manage memory allocation yourself actually?

Comment: Variable argument lists is more a question of the [Application Binary Interface (ABI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). If both the C and C++ source is compiled using the same ABI then they should be compatible.

Comment: In C, you pass the `va_list` by value, not by reference — your C++ code is showing that it is being passed by reference.  Does it work better in C++ if you remove the `&` from the definition (of `void HttpDaemon::parseMessageVa(void * arg, const char * fmt, va_list &ap)`)?

Comment: @PeteBecker This was the answer. Thanks. If you write it as an answer then I will mark it as such.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, you are correct, a std::vector<char> would have been much better. This is my first use of va_list and I based my code on an example. I should have done a full rewrite.

Comment: I'm not sure what the downvotes were for. Perhaps if someone (ideally those that gave them) could tell me then I can ask a better question next time.

Comment: Why do you expect two different languages to behave identical? And C does not support references.

Comment: @Olaf Without going into language arguments, but in the context of Windows `va_list` is part of the ABI (APIs like `wvsprintf` use it), and the Win32 API *can* be used from C++, so it is natural to assume that the compatiblity extends to one's own code.

Comment: @dxiv: Apparently not, as you cannot pass C++ types to a C function (that is not specific to windows). Note: you can call C functions from Python or Fortran. Does that make Python or Fortran the same language?

Comment: @Olaf The question was not about `two different languages to behave identically`. It was very narrowly about interoperability of `va_list` arguments between `C` and `C++` in `Windows`.

Comment: @PhilRosenberg: Not my DV, but I tend to. It should be obvious you cannot pass C++ types to C, but only the common set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`va_list &ap` -- a callback from C won't pass anything by reference. The function should take the list by value.